# Table from a tree structure, how to select branches then partition more info for each branch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table describing a geographical structure, which is built like a tree structure, where column1 is the 'country', column2 contains the largest administrative area called 'region1', then 'region2' column contains children of region1 etc.

So this

```
                     r
     /               |               \
     1               2               3
/    |     \    /    |     \    /    |     \
11   12    13   21   22    23   31   32     33
```

Is represesented like this for each distinct combination:

```
cntry|  r1  |  r2
------------------
  r  |  1   |  11
  r  |  1   |  12
  r  |  1   |  13
  r  |  2   |  21
  r  |  2   |  22
  r  |  2   |  23
  r  |  3   |  31
  r  |  3   |  32
  r  |  3   |  33
```

In addition, each leaf node contains some additional info, which can span multiple rows. such as zip code. So the table *actually* looks something like this:

```
cntry| r1   |  r2  |  zip |
--------------------------|
  r  |  1   |  11  |  a   |
  r  |  1   |  11  |  aa  |
  r  |  1   |  11  |  aaa |
  r  |  1   |  11  |  aaaa|
  r  |  1   |  12  |  b   |
  r  |  1   |  13  |  c   |
  r  |  1   |  13  |  cc  |
  r  |  1   |  13  |  ccc |
  r  |  2   |  21  |  d   |
  r  |  2   |  22  |  e   |
  r  |  2   |  22  |  ee  |
  r  |  2   |  23  |  f   |
  r  |  3   |  31  |  g   |
  r  |  3   |  31  |  gg  |
  r  |  3   |  31  |  ggg |
  r  |  3   |  32  |  h   |
  r  |  3   |  33  |  i   |
```

Now, the real table contains almost two million rows, with lots of text in the columns for place names. That's a lot of duplicate info in the additional rows where just the zip code is the new information. It takes up bandwidth and is slow.

Is it possible to make a query to select the cntry,r1,r2 distinctly and ordered, but with the zip rows following each distinct row with `null` in the other columns? So the result of the select would look like this:

```
cntry| r1   |  r2  |  zip |
--------------------------|
  r  |  1   |  11  |  a   |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  aa  |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  aaa |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  aaaa|
  r  |  1   |  12  |  b   |
  r  |  1   |  13  |  c   |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  cc  |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  ccc |
  r  |  2   |  21  |  d   |
  r  |  2   |  22  |  e   |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  ee  |
  r  |  2   |  23  |  f   |
  r  |  3   |  31  |  g   |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  gg  |
 NULL| NULL | NULL |  ggg |
  r  |  3   |  32  |  h   |
  r  |  3   |  33  |  i   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by cntry, r1, r2 order by zip) as row_num
   from tbl
)
select
    case when c.row_num = 1 then cntry end as cntry,
    case when c.row_num = 1 then r1 end as r1,
    case when c.row_num = 1 then r2 end as r2,
    c.zip
from cte as c
order by c.r1, c.r2, row_num
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/039c5/5)